# Strange behavior when multithreading using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

There are 2 threads in my application - one UI, and the second is updating some data. The class of the second thread inherits the `wxThread` class, and has some variables, in particular, `Worker *worker`.

```
class Worker {
public:
    virtual void work() {}
};

class WorkerThread : public wxThread {
public:
    bool isRunning = true;
    Worker *worker;

    virtual ExitCode Entry() {
        while (isRunning) {
            if (worker == nullptr) continue;
            worker->work();
            usleep(UPDATE_DELAY_USEC);
        }

        std::cout << "Done\n";

        return 0;
    }
};
```

If I change the value of the worker from the first thread to `nullptr`, the application will continue working fine. If, for example, I change the value to `new Worker()` or the same value as it was, the application will simply exit. Without any errors printed to the console.

I change this pointer in `wxNotebook` events:

```
void onPageChanged(wxBookCtrlEvent &event) {
    switch (event.GetOldSelection()) {
        case MNP_PROCESSES:
            workerThread->worker = nullptr;
            break;
    }

    switch (event.GetSelection()) {
        case MNP_PROCESSES:
            workerThread->worker = &processes->worker;
            break;
    }
}
```

The whole strange thing is that if I bring the `Worker *worker` to the global scope, then everything will work fine, without any errors.

```
Worker *worker;

class WorkerThread : public wxThread {
    ...
```

What is the reason?

Comment: It isn't very clear how "working fine" and "simply exit" are correlated.  But it is buggy, you can't change the variable without synchronization.  If for example you update the value to nullptr and the thread happens to use it right after the if-statement then it will bomb.  Not the only problem, it isn't volatile so good odds that it will just keep using the old value.  Unless you make it global.  Synchronization required.

Comment: wxWidgets requires all GUI operations to be performed in one thread.   https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_thread.html

Comment: @stark, all GUI operations pass in one thread

Comment: @HansPassant, you said: "If for example you update the value to nullptr and the thread happens to use it right after the if-statement then it will bomb", yes, I understand that, nullptr was used for an example

Comment: I was able to get an error message using gdb: `Thread 1 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. workerThread->worker = &processes->worker;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. I was looking for a problem where there is none. The problem was that I first created a `wxNotebook`, respectively, `onPageChanged` was called, in which the pointer changed, which belonged to a class that had not yet been created.